# Optimising two for loops in Python

Tags: python, performance, django

I would like to make this code more efficient, I have isolated the problem as being these two for loops:

```
    for i, device in enumerate(list_devices):
        for data_type_attr_name in data_types:
            result_list_element = {
                "device_reference": device.name,
                "device_name": "REF - " + device.name,
                "data_type": data_type_attr_name,
                "type": next(
                    (data_type["type"] for data_type in DATA_TYPES if data_type["name"] == data_type_attr_name)
                ),
                "data_points": getattr(device, data_type_attr_name)(
                    is_last_value=is_last_value,
                    from_timestamp=from_timestamp,
                    to_timestamp=to_timestamp,
                    aggregate_period_name=aggregate_period_name,
                    aggregate_operation_name=aggregate_operation_name,
                    decimal_places=decimal_places,
                ),
            }
            if not isinstance(result_list_element["data_points"], list):
                raise TypeError("`data_points` must be returned as a list, even if it contains only one element.")
            result_list.append(result_list_element)

    return result_list
```

`list_devices` is a list of Django model objects, `data_types` is a list of strings, each one representing a data type.

Is there any way of losing one of the for loops while maintaining the same output?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
import itertools

for device, data_type_attr_name in itertools.product(list_devices, data_types):
    result_list_element = {
        "device_reference": device.name,
        "device_name": "REF - " + device.name,
        "data_type": data_type_attr_name,
        "type": next((data_type["type"] for data_type in DATA_TYPES if data_type["name"] == data_type_attr_name)),
        "data_points": getattr(device, data_type_attr_name)(
            is_last_value=is_last_value,
            from_timestamp=from_timestamp,
            to_timestamp=to_timestamp,
            aggregate_period_name=aggregate_period_name,
            aggregate_operation_name=aggregate_operation_name,
            decimal_places=decimal_places,
        ),
    }
    if not isinstance(result_list_element["data_points"], list):
        raise TypeError("`data_points` must be returned as a list, even if it contains only one element.")
    result_list.append(result_list_element)
return result_list
```

Answer (score 3):

Assume you are referring to speed, not conciseness when asking about efficiency. In which case reducing the amount of loops will not necessarily improve performance.

```
"type": next((data_type["type"] for data_type in DATA_TYPES if data_type["name"] == data_type_attr_name))
```

This can be improved so that you are not needing to go over `DATA_TYPES` looking for a matching name to `data_type_attr_name` every iteration. Instead you can make a reverse lookup dictionary once before the loop where `data_type["name"]` is the key.

Whenever you are searching through a list often, it can be very beneficial to create a dictionary.